# How do i retreive the values of belongs to relationship

Tags: laravel

I want the retrieve the values of a belongsTo relationship. The values are returning but when i use for loop, it is returning `object of property [] not found`.

This is the returned json [user_request] on blade:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "henry",
  "email": "wvanye@ymail.com",
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "created_at": "2019-05-15 19:04:42",
  "updated_at": "2019-05-15 19:04:42",
  "Affiliate": "FMS",
  "admin": 0
}
```

My code:

```
examrequest model
class examrequest extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'examrequest';

  public function users(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id');
  }
}


Controller
public function getRequest(){
  $request = examrequest::first()->users;

    $count = $this->isThereRequest();
    return view('admin.request', ['user_request'=>$request]);
 }

blade view
@foreach ($user_request as $key => $value )
    <tr>
     <th scope="row"></th>
     <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
     <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
     <td><button>Approve</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

I want to display all the values but its returning :: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a collection to loop through, you won't get that if you use `first()`, as this won't pull a collection, but rather a single object.   Change

```
$request = examrequest::first()->users;
```

to

```
$request = examrequest::with('users')->get();
```

The collection of examrequests will all be inside $`request` at this point.

On the blade side, if you want to loop on that collection and pull each user, you can simplify by just pulling the user from the foreach.  Change:

```
@foreach ($user_request as $key => $value )
```

to

```
@foreach ($user_request as $request )
```

and then pull the fields you need from the user relation on the `$request` object:  `$request->users->id`... etc within the loop on the blade page.

Comment: Ohkay, so how do i point to the users function in the examrequest model?

Comment: Because when i do that i get [{"id":2,"user_id":1,"exam_id":1,"approve":1,"created_at":"2019-05-14 16:30:04","updated_at":"2019-05-14 16:30:04"}]  but what i want to return are the belongsto relationship the users in the exam request model

Comment: Try this - it should work for you now :)  We weren't accessing the relationship.  By lazy loading and calling it in the loop, this should solve your issue

Comment: yeah i know, its meant to return this: {"id":2,"name":"henry","email":"wvanye@ymail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2019-05-15 19:04:42","updated_at":"2019-05-15 19:04:42","Affiliate":"FMS","admin":0}  but instead: it returns this json array [{"id":2,"user_id":1,"exam_id":1,"approve":1,"created_at":"2019-05-14 16:30:04","updated_at":"2019-05-14 16:30:04"}]

Comment: belongs to will only return one.  Sorry, I was looking for your output based on the loop.  But that loop will never loop more than once, as you only have one user  assigned.  You can change your relationship to belongs to many and this will work, OR `foreach($user_request as $request)` and THEN that `$request` will have your user.  So , based on that change above, inside the blade: `<td>{{$request->users->name}}</td}}  Strongly suggest you change relationship name from users to user to avoid confusion

Comment: I am currently getting an error based on the all();  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()

Comment: I'll edit my answer - try with get.  Now that we're lazy loading, it prefers get() see edit:

Comment: BULLSEYE. THANKS ALOT CLARK KENT #FistBump